# GridView Button Not Setting When Reloading GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am populating a GridView programmatically and I have paging enabled. My GridView is populated on a DropDown_SelectedIndexChanged handler, and it loads the first page of the new selection successfully. I do this by resetting the PageIndex to 0. However, when I selected a new value in the dropdown, the Page Buttons (using Numeric page buttons) do not reset. So we have page 1 showing, but the page 5 button (or whicheverI last clicked) is selected. This could be confusing to users. How can I reset the button that is selected? Is there a property that sets the selected button for paging?

EDIT: The following code is really all I have. The populatePanelGridView() function isn't doing anything related to the pages, it's just adding items.

```
    protected void DropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //changing the dropdown selection (aka when the page should revert to 1)
{
    populatePanelGridView();
    PanelGridView.PageIndex = 0;

}

    protected void PanelGridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e) //changing the page
{
    PanelGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    populatePanelGridView();

}
```

Comment: Added a bit of code, there's not really much I'm doing with pages that would help...

Comment: Added some more code, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it the other way round, first change the `PageIndex`, then `DataBind` the `GridView`:

```
PanelGridView.PageIndex = 0;
populatePanelGridView();
```

Comment: I'm still having some issues. I will investigate further and come back here.

Comment: I made this change in the wrong section of the code. This works. 
Thanks!